# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2

Tags: java, android, pushe

when i use this library :

```
compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.0'
```

I get this error in gradle:

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2
```

I can't fix it.

There is a solution to be there library Ignored
 `'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'` from `'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.0'` ?

Because I have already compiled a newer version of support-v4 library.

All my dependencies code in gradle :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+' //--> its ok and no problem
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.0' //--->this code is error Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons which can cause this kind of problem.
Checkout these solution, I guess it might help you:
1. Remove **Pushe** and try adding `support-v4` library with version of `26.0.2` to make sure it gets downloaded and cached to your system.
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2' // or implementation`

If it still can't be resolved then you have a problem getting it from it's repository server. checkout `build.gradle(project:your_prj)` and make sure this block is valid.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // or maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' } for lower gradles
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

If your country is included in sanction you might need to use a VPN to be able to get them. You can also use a proxy like [Fod](https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod)(also donate if you can since it's opensource) or [shecan](https://shecan.ir).
Remember all support libraries better be `26.0.2` to avoid conflict and crashing. Your support libraries are `26.0.0-alpha1` which is lower.

2. After you successfully added and cached `support-v4` then try to add **Pushe** to your dependencies again.

**!** *And also remember that pushe has a support-v4 bundled in it and it's not really needed for you to add it yourself*

<s>And Make sure you have</s>

<s>`<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="co.ronash.pushe" />`</s>

in you manifest. Therefore you can override it's libraries and dependencies.
At the end keep your **SDK** update.
**Edit:**
Current version of `Pushe` is using **android support libraries**. If you attend to use **AndroidX** be sure to enable `jettifier` in order to do runtime conversion.

Comment: support-v4 is not compatible with androidx. in order to fix that i set `android.useAndroidX` and `android.enableJetifier` to true.

Comment: The currrent version of `pushe` has support-v4 bundled in itself. Isn't it a concern? Because of the library you might not be able to use `androidX`. Am i right?

Comment: I am confused about that as well. but it seems it fixed the problem for me. i got similar error here and this answer fixed my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472281/4767498

Comment: `AndroidX` also has `jettifier` which does **runtime conversion** of supportlib to androidX packages. So no worries about that.