# Error while merging dex Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Error when merging the dex

following are the dependencies.

```
ext {
    anko_version='0.10.5'
    support_lib='1.0.0-alpha1'
    room_lib = "1.1.0"
}
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$support_lib"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$support_lib"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$support_lib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_lib"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_lib"
}
```

error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar,
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find anything?

Comment: Same here. Seems like some libs are not compatible with androidx for now. I'm using anko and android-dialogs and both of them are not working - even when setting `enableJetifier`:-(

Comment: Please refer to this answer. This really worked for me.
[Multidex issue with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454/7728984)

Answer (score 93):

It's because you messed up the dependencies. You have to either fully migrate to AndroidX dependencies or stay on Support library ones. Thus,
instead of

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_lib"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_lib"
```

use

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

Also be sure to check your `gradle.properties` project file to contain

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Jetifier helps libraries, which depend on old Support packages, to use the new AndroidX ones.

What is Jetifier?
It's an Android Gradle Plugin task (now can also be used as a standalone tool) which is invoked during build phase. AGP (>= 3.2.0) does automatically apply dependency translation which rewrites bytecode and resources of JAR and AAR dependencies (and transitive dependencies) to reference the new androidx-packaged classes and artifacts.
You can also use it as a standalone tool to individually migrate a library.

[Jetifier Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier)

> The standalone Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead. The tool lets you migrate an individual library directly, instead of using the Android gradle plugin bundled with Android Studio.

P. S. I didn't test if Anko works with AndroidX dependencies, but if it doesn't even though those properties in your `gradle.properties` are enabled, you have no other choices, but fallback to using Support libraries as for now.

Comment: Thanks for your help I has missing gradle.properties setting

Comment: i had no idea why enableJetifier should work until you explained it. thanks

Comment: +1 for the second sentence. Just a tiny addition though: this isn't just related to the dependencies like `android.arch.persistence.room:...`, but also any dependencies that use those. `enableJetifier` is effectively a shortcut that forces use of the jetpack dependencies over support packages, which is useful for dependencies that haven't migrated yet.

Comment: Halellujah. I thaught I'd have to deal with this dependency duplication nightmare on every project. Thanks for the explanation. I've lost so much time before hitting this answer.

Answer (score 18):

add following lines on `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and change your room dependencies on  build.gradle(moudel:app)

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

Comment: glad to hear @Po10cio

Answer (score 9):

Migrate the dependencies to `androidx` dependencies. And in `gradle.properties` add the below lines (If not created already, create the file in root folder).

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me was Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX option in Android Studio.  This seemed to resolve any things I may have missed when trying to do the AndroidX migration one dependency at a time.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Do not mix dependencies styles(androidx and com.android.support) in your project.

In your code try to replace

`implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$support_lib"`

with

`implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$version_of_support_library"`

A full list of dependencies migration you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor?authuser=3) .

I should use old style dependency because I needed WorkManager and according to official documentation WorkManager currently without AndroidX dependencies.

> WorkManager classes are already in the androidx.work package, but
>   currently depend on Support Library 27.1, and associated Arch
>   component versions. Version of WorkManager with AndroidX dependencies
>   will be released in the future.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX option in Android Studio.  This seemed to resolve any things I may have missed when trying to do the AndroidX migration one dependency at a time.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 2):

Check the package which clashes with the com.android.support and exclude it
from that package. For me, I was using androidx packages and also FCM, where
there was a clash. So, this fixed for me:

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Following plugins

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Add these two lines in platforms/android/gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Here is a video as well:
https://youtu.be/0RaJlGipYHc

Answer (score 0):

for my instance i had upgraded from 
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0
to
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

Comment: do you mean that glide 4.7.1 can be used with androidx? As far as I know it does not support androidx yet

Comment: @kingston I guess it has the support libs it needs bundled in it. So using `androidX` will cause **Mix**.