# Can I use library that used android support with Androidx projects.

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I know, [androidx and support dependency causing multidex error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387207/error-while-merging-dex-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resu)
We can not use androidx and android support at a same time. So I totally migrate to androidx. but one of my dependency lib used android support "lottie".

What can we do in above situation? Should I remove 'lottie' from my project.

below is my gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    ext{
    lottieVersion = "2.5.4"
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    def androidx = "1.0.0-rc01"
    api "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2"
    api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidx"
    api "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidx"
    api "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidx"
    api "androidx.core:core-ktx:$androidx"
    api "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"
    }
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can enable `Jetifier` on your project, which will basically exchange the `Android Support Library` dependencies in your project dependencies with `AndroidX`-ones. (e.g. Your Lottie dependencies will be changed from Support to AnroidX)

From the Android Studio Documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/):

> The Android Gradle plugin provides the following global flags that you
>   can set in your gradle.properties file:
>
> - android.useAndroidX: When set to true, this flag indicates that you want to start using AndroidX from now on. If the flag is absent,
>     Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to false.
> - android.enableJetifier: When set to true, this flag indicates that you want to have tool support (from the Android Gradle plugin) to
>     automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were
>     written for AndroidX. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as
>     if the flag were set to false.

Precondition for Jetifier:

- you have to use at least `Android Studio 3.2`

To enable jetifier, add those two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Finally, please check the release notes of AndroidX, because `jetifier` has still some problems with some libraries (e.g. Dagger Android): https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn

Comment: My project uses multiple libraries, some of them uses support library while some of uses androidx. How do i use both libraries in my project?

Comment: @hiren dabhi Can you create a new question for your setup, if the solution proposal is not working for you? It's rather difficult to find an answer without knowing more details about your setup.

Answer (score 64):

Manually adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` giving me hard time. Because it's throw some error or   `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application>`

To Enable Jet-fire in project there is option in android Studio

Select Your Project ---> Right Click

app----> Refactor ----> Migrate to AndroidX

Shown in below image:-

[image]

After click on **Migrate to AndroidX**.

It will ask for confirmation and back up for your project.

[image]

And last step it will ask you for to do refactor.

[image]

After doing Refactor check your gradle.properties have `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`. If they are not then add these two lines to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

> Note:- Upgrading using Android Studio, this option works if you have
>   android studio 3.2 and onward. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: good suggestion, but just a side note for people upgrading using Android Studio, this option works if you have android studio 3.2 and onward. Check this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 23):

**You need not to worry**

Just enable [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview) in your projet.

- [Update Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/) to 3.2.0 or newer.
- Open `gradle.properties` and add below two lines.

  ```
  android.enableJetifier=true
  android.useAndroidX=true
  ```

It will convert all support libraries of your dependency to AndroidX at run time (you may have compile time errors, but app will run).

Comment: gradle.properties was not found in my files, created myself

Comment: in fact, a transitive dependency + gradle cache might not works, even `android.enableJetifier=true`, if this happened, I think manually using `jetifier-standalone` to the 3rd-party aar, might works.

Comment: I have android studio 4.1  . I did enable Jetifier. My app is not running.

Comment: @Khemraj even adding Jetifier into gradle.properties, it started showing compile time errors everywhere in the project , where there is usage of V4 support library. So theres only option left is to  fix and migrate all code into AndroidX manually. Which was not an option for me.

Comment: i have create a Question here for same :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716862/mpandroidchart-by-enabling-android-useandroidx-true-my-existing-code-and-xml-t?noredirect=1#comment114428191_64716862

Answer (score 12):

Add the lines in the **gradle.properties** file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image]
[image]
Refer also
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Answer (score 3):

I added below two lines in gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then I got the following error

```
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
                         ^
```

I have removed the imports and added below line

```
import static android.app.AlertDialog.*;
```

And the classes which are extended from AppCompactActivity, added the below line. (For these errors you just need to press alt+enter in android studio which will import the correct library for you. Like this you can resolve all the errors)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

In your xml file if you have used any

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

replace it with `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

then in your java code

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 2):

Open gradle.properties and add below two lines.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

And you will face a new issues, here is the solution.
My problem was solved after adding **android:exported="true"** on **android.intent.category.LAUNCHER** Activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"> // Add this line
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used these two lines of code in application tag in manifest.xml and it worked.

```
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"    
 android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Source: https://github.com/android/android-ktx/issues/576#issuecomment-437145192

Answer (score 1):

API 29.+ usage AndroidX libraries. If you are using API 29.+, then you cannot remove these. If you want to remove AndroidX, then you need to remove the entire 29.+ API from your SDK:

[image: SDK Settings]

This will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Add the lines in the `gradle.properties` file

  ```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
  ```
- If you are getting any errors while building the apk then you have to export the activities by adding `android:exported="true"` tag in all activities on `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.examplerealtime">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        ...
    >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ...
            android:exported="true">
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not AndroidX (mean Appcompat) and got this error, try to downgrade dependencies versions that triggers this error, in my case play-services-location ("implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'") , I solved the problem by downgrading to com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before, it was the gradle.properties file doesn't exist, only the gradle.properties.txt , so i went to my project folder and i copied & pasted the gradle.properties.txt file but without .txt extension then it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the project folder, in build.gradle(Module:Application)

   - Fix compileSdkVersion to 28
   - If targetSdkVersion is defined, change this to 28
   - After modifying like that, if you click Sync Now at the top, an error will appear.
2. In the Refactor menu, click Migration to AndroidX to proceed with the migration.
3. After that, if you open gradle.properties in the Project folder, you will see the definition as below

   android.enableJetifier=true
   android.useAndroidX=true

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Click on Refactor, Migrate to androidX and then follow the prompts.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
```

I went to `gradle.properties` and added the following line:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Then the error is different for me:

```
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$ConnectionCallbackInternal found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionResultReceiver found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemCallback$StubApi23 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ItemReceiver found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImpl found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$2 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$3 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$4 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$5 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$6 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi21$7 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi23 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplApi26 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$2 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$3 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$4 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$5 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$6 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserImplBase$MediaServiceConnection$2 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaBrowserServiceCallbackImpl found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$MediaItem$Flags found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SearchCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SearchResultReceiver found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ServiceBinderWrapper found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$Subscription found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback$StubApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$SubscriptionCallback$StubApi26 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$ConnectionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$ConnectionCallbackProxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$MediaItem found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$SubscriptionCallbackProxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23$ItemCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi23$ItemCallbackProxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26$SubscriptionCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi26$SubscriptionCallbackProxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat$Builder found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompatApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompatApi21$Builder found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompatApi23 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompatApi23$Builder found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$BitmapKey found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$Builder found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$LongKey found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$RatingKey found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat$TextKey found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompatApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompatApi21$Builder found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.ParceledListSliceAdapterApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat$1 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat$StarStyle found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat$Style found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaControllerCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaControllerCallback$Stub found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaControllerCallback$Stub$Proxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaSession found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaSession$Stub found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.IMediaSession$Stub$Proxy found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$Callback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$Callback$MessageHandler found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$Callback$StubApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$Callback$StubCompat found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerExtraData found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImpl found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplApi21 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplApi21$ExtraBinderRequestResultReceiver found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplApi21$ExtraCallback found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat$MediaControllerImplApi23 found in modules media-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0) and support-media-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserActionsFallbackMenuAdapter found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserActionsFallbackMenuAdapter$ViewHolderItem found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
Duplicate class androidx.browser.browseractions.BrowserActionsFallbackMenuDialog found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and customtabs-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0)
com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder$CenterComparator found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder$FurthestFromAverageComparator found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternInfo found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.BlockPair found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.ByteMatrix found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder$1 found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.MaskUtil found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.MatrixUtil found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.QRCode found in modules core (core.jar) and core-3.3 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3)
    
    Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I added `android.enableJetifier=true` to `gradle.properties` and the errors above were gone.

Answer (score -3):

Comment This Line in `gradle.properties`

> android.useAndroidX=true

Comment: OP is asking whether it is possible to use AndroidX with Android Support.
You suggest to disable AndroidX

Comment: go to gradle.properties and comment