# ViewPager2 config in project using androidX

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

My project running well without implementing ViewPager2 gradle in my application. But when i use its gradle `implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha01'` in my project it giving me this Log-cat error...

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:557: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:557: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:834: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\anonymous\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e2e18b400b8fa36a8523d44c560bb82c\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\sam\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.sam.test.sushil\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\sam\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Same error with this `implementation group: 'androidx.viewpager2', name:'viewpager2', version: '1.0.0-alpha01'`

Then i created another empty project and implemented `implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha01'`

and it gives me this error.....

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha04] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Above error specific there is conflict between `android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory` which is `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and `implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha01'`. So i removed the `support:appcompat` library from my project.

And it is working Now.

My question is

If i remove `support:appcompat` I can't use AppCompatActivity and its uses. Which is present in my existing application.

**How to resolve this ?**

**How I can use `ViewPager2` as well as `support:appcompat` together?**

**Edit**

@ManoharReddy after adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` inside `<application>` tag of manifest. It gives me this error

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:540)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Post your whole `build.gradle`

Comment: Its suggesting to add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` inside `<application>` tag of manifest , just do it and check once

Comment: here is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects), enable `jetifier`.

Comment: @KishoreJethava after enabling jetfire in my existing project it is giving me same error.

Comment: @ManoharReddy please check new error which is came after enabling tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" inside <application> tag

Comment: Why don't you use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0`? and re-import `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I did not using any `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0` in my project.

Comment: This version of ViewPager2 is released for Android X so if you want to use it then your project must have been migrated to Android X.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan but it is working in my new project if i removed in `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

As @Kishore and @Shweta told to migrate the AndroidX in project is the solution.

Manually adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` giving me hard time. Because it's throw some error or   `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application>`

To Enable Jet-fire in project there is option in android Studio

Select Your Project ---> Right Click

app----> Refactor ----> Migrate to AndroidX

Shown in below image:-

[image]

After click on **Migrate to AndroidX**.

It will ask for confirmation and back up for your project.

[image]

And last step it will ask you for to do refactor.

[image]

After doing Refactor check your gradle.properties have `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`. If they are not then add these two lines to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Thanks all the user for help.