# Jetifier not working when library uses android component and app uses androidx component

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

I have an app where I am using AncdroidX components. Jetifier is enabled

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Now i am adding a third party library which uses android libraries instead of AndroidX `(com.android.support).`

Library dependencies

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

App Dependenciews

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
```

I am getting build error for the third party library

```
error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
    public final android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbarFragment;
                                          ^
```

When I checked dependencies, it is showing as

```
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.4 -> androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.2.1
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0 (*)
```

Comment: This is the entire purpose of jetifier. Does the library generate code by any chance?

Comment: Which is the 3rd party library? is the wrong import in your code?

Comment: `implementation 'com.xxx.sdk:yyy:1.2.8-RELEASE'` This is how I am importing it in my gradle file @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't understand your question

Comment: look at solutions from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects/52034414

Comment: I cannot change the code of third party library or ask them to upgrade their code. I need to fix this in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the app is generating the binding classes and Jetifier fails to migrate the code in generated classes. To solve this problem, the library provider needs to put

> android.databinding.enableV2=true

in their `gradle.properties` file.

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#preview-compiler)

> Binding classes for library modules are compiled and packaged into the corresponding Android Archive (AAR) file. App modules that depend on those library modules no longer need to regenerate the binding classes.

Comment: what library did you use? did you try to use `jetifier-standalone` instead for the 3rd-party library aar? then implement the library aar locally, e.g: `implementation project(:jetified-libs)`