# Add androidx support for external library

Tags: android, external, androidx

I migrated my Android project to androidX and now facing several issues with support for androidX. I was able to fix some of them with upgrading the external library to its latest version to support androidX. But I have other libraries that are not maintained for several years. For example I am using the KenBurnsView and get following error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val Activity.ivStoryItem: KenBurnsView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_story_item
public val Dialog.ivStoryItem: KenBurnsView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_story_item
public val android.app.Fragment.ivStoryItem: KenBurnsView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_story_item
public val android.support.v4.app.Fragment.ivStoryItem: KenBurnsView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_story_item
public val View.ivStoryItem: KenBurnsView! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_story_item.view
```

I already tried to exclude the support.v4. library in the KenBurnsView but it did not help. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you added these lines to gradle.properties:
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: This will force third-party libraries to use AndroidX.

Comment: yes its done automatically by migrating to android X

Comment: Like a variant you can download the source code of your library and migrate it to AndroidX. And after that add it to your app (like apk or android library)

Comment: @MaratZangiev so you mean the only solution is to fork each library and add support for androidX by myself?

Comment: I think it is a good idea. Especially you say: "library is not maintained for several years".

Comment: oops, in above comment not "like apk or android library" but "like jar or android library"

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding jetifier and androidx flags to `gradle.properties` file.

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

Here you have the reason : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034414/12009871