# Can I use a library that used AndroidX libs in my App with Android-support libs?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

actually this question is totally the opposite to this one.

[Can I use library that used android support with Androidx projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects)

And I knew there has been a trick to handle the above question
by this config

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

However, I'm not sure is there another trick for the opposite case. When an App uses a libs which depend on AndroidX, but at the same time, the App also has dependencies on Android-support libs.

```
The example dependencies

    +--- App 
    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
    |    +--- Lib#1
    |    |    |
    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I think we can use either androidx library or support library. we can;t use both on same project.

Comment: You have to migrate to androidx. Just an example with the latest firebase libraries which require androidx migration.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use support libraries along with androidx package structure

please take a look official [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)