# How to make CameraX continuous scanning for barcode app

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I'm looking into the CameraX library, I wonder if it's possible to make it Continuous scanning on barcodes?.

Right now I'm using the

**me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13**

this library works fine. But I want to migrate to androidX and it seems not supported at the moment with this lib. any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use library that used android support with Androidx projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate to androidx and still use your barcode library. What you need to do is enable jetifier in your project, you need to add the following to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002285/8103819).