# How to have Android-Support and Android-X at same time for different SDKs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dependency-management, android-library

I have an `Android SDK` that contains two dependencies in it, they are :

```
android-support-v4

android-support-v7-appcompat
```

When I add this `Android SDK` into a Unity application And add `Google Play Game` plugin into it, I'll get an error in compile time. Error is about duplicate dependencies.

The problem is the `Google Play Game` plugin used `AndroidX` in it and the `Android SDK` used `android-support` dependency.

It's not possible to migrate the `Android SDK` to `AndroidX`.

So how can I deal with this situation?

Comment: have you seen this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects

Comment: @Umair
I'm  using  '''internal''' build system in unity, not '''Gradle''' build system

Answer (score 1):

Use [Play Services Resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) to resolve all your dependencies issues.