# Problem compiling android app, dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

a while ago I made a little app. Unfortunately this was one year ago and something seems to have changed in my IDE or project again.

I can hit assembleDebug and end up with an apk file of my app. No errors show up in the log.
When I try to open it on my device it will always say: a problem occurred when parsing the package. When I take a look into my build.grade I see that the appcompat dependency is underlined red.

If anyone can give a hint on how to have a good workflow I'd really appreciate it.
Unfortunately I always get those and similar problems. I don't even risk updating my IDE anymore and am very frustrated. I am yet more a hobby developer and not concerned about having my apps always up to date with the lates android,gradlde version what so ever since I am still far away from releasing anything. I just want to code and open my project and be able to continue. I really don't understand what is always corrupting my setup, since my phone wasn't updated in the meanwhile either.

Any help is appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Support Libraries are no longer supported starting API Level 29. You need to replace the dependency to following :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Nice, it worked, changed to 1.1.0
My mistake was setting min sdk version to 29 but my phone uses 25.... :D

Answer (score 0):

Migration to Android X would solve the issue. Here are the steps based on the recent talk at [Android Dev Summit '19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hyt7LR5mXLc) :

1. Make sure your `minSdkVersion` is at least 28.
2. [Enable Jetifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034414/5339154) by putting these lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

3. Check whether your dependencies of third-party libraries you use are up-to-date.
4. Use Android Studio tool for migrating by clicking on `Refactor - Migrate to Android X...`

This way, you may avoid a lot of headache by following the first 3 steps right before using that tool.

Comment: My min sdk version is 29, I added the two lines to my empty gradle.properties file.
I don`t use any third-party libs.

When I hit Migrate to Android X it ends saying "no usages found in this project"

Comment: @yesyoor Try to run your app on emulator or another real device. Your underlining is rather a warning than an error. I assume you need to enable app installation from unknown sources on your device which faced the issue

Comment: I am trying to run it on my phone. unknown sources are allowed there.  Android version7.0. the parsing error appears on my phone

Comment: okay it was my own bad. my phone uses sdk25 and I had minsdk version set to 29...