# How to use both Androidx libraries and support libraries in one project?

Tags: java, android, androidx

androidx and com.android.support
I want to use both lib in one project
As we are using one sdk that uses androidx and 
my sdk don't use androidx what to do how to use 
it in one project ??

Comment: I dont believe you can do that

Comment: what makes you do that? there is jetifier to convert support library dependent dependencies to androidx

Comment: I am integrating one third party sdk in which there dependencies are in androidx and in my current project we are not using androidx

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `Jetifier` on your project, which will basically exchange the `Android Support Library` dependencies in your project dependencies with `AndroidX`-ones. (e.g. Your Lottie dependencies will be changed from Support to AnroidX)

From the Android Studio Documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/):

> The Android Gradle plugin provides the following global flags that you
>   can set in your gradle.properties file:
>
> - android.useAndroidX: When set to true, this flag indicates that you want to start using AndroidX from now on. If the flag is absent,
>     Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to false.
> - android.enableJetifier: When set to true, this flag indicates that you want to have tool support (from the Android Gradle plugin) to
>     automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were
>     written for AndroidX. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as
>     if the flag were set to false.

Precondition for Jetifier:

- you have to use at least `Android Studio 3.2`

To enable jetifier, add those two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Finally, please check the release notes of AndroidX, because `jetifier` has still some problems with some libraries (e.g. Dagger Android): https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn

Answer Credit: Christopher https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034414/9932194