# Can I use library that uses Androidx with support library project?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetpack

My project uses support library and library which i have added as dependency uses androidx.Can i build app without replacing my project's support library APIs with  androidx?

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects) answer but my question is opposite of that.

Comment: No, to use a lib that uses AndroidX, your project has to be AndroidX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using support libraries is not a recommended practice anymore, and you should migrate to androidx as soon as possible. Migration is easy, and Android Studio takes care of the heavy lifting for you.