# implementation 'com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0' showing error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

started a new blank template project and just after adding draglinearlayout dependency i started getting these errors, while before adding this dependency i ran my project and it worked fine. the error is as follows

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-22.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-22.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-v4-22.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1)
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

this is the error i'm getting

and this is my module grade file

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.ujjwal.drag_and_drop"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation 'com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android has a solution to this problem where a new Android project uses AndroidX with some old libraries that use the legacy android support libraries, you are in that case.

The solution is to enable Jetifier in your `gradle.properties`, like this:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

You can find more info in these two posts:

- [Can I use library that used android support with Androidx projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033810/can-i-use-library-that-used-android-support-with-androidx-projects)
- [What is Jetifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier)