# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Tags: android, gradle

I have been trying to solve this error for 2 days now , with no luck. I have been searching everywhere, most of the solutions tell me to remove '+'s from the dependencies. But I already don't have any '+'. I am using absolute version codes. The project was working fine until I integrated the Material Drawer by Mikepenz. And Material Drawer worked fine without the header, when I add the header I get 'ResourceNotFound' error. To resolve that some people said to change the 'Compile SDK Version' in the 'Project Structure'. When I change it to 'Android-P' , I get the mentioned error. When I set it to '27 Oreo', I get another error:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1207: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1207: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Danis\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\c643f693a5e3c12b475023c52cd701d5\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Danis\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.spesa.spesabudgetmanager\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\SpesaBudgetManager\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Here is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spesa.spesabudgetmanager"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yesterselga:country-picker-android:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.midorikocak:currency-picker-android:1.1.9'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialize:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:3.3.0@aar'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387207/error-while-merging-dex-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resu

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery Doing that makes it worse. Android says it can't resolve AppCompat, and I also get the ' Android resource linking failed' error.

Comment: Most probably `"mikepenz"` libs are using `androidx`. So can you try adding 

  `android.useAndroidX=true`
  `android.enableJetifier=true`

in `gradle.properties`

Comment: I am Already Answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676100/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resultreceivermyresultrecei/55345901#55345901

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably some libs are using androidx.

To find which one, run

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

find a line like this

```
yourapp:dependencies
```

use it to get the dependency tree

```
./gradlew yourapp:dependencies
```

Pert of my dependency tree

[image]

In my case it was the Advanced RecyclerView, in their page there is this notice "v1.0.0 Migrated to AndroidX (Use v0.11.0 instead if your project uses support libraries)" So i followed the advice and my problem was solved.