# Import ML-Vision library in project with Support Library

Tags: android, androidx, gradle-dependencies, mlvision

Is it possible to add the following dependency
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:23.0.0'`
in a project that is not migrated to AndroidX libraries?

I gave it a try and it seems that I have to migrate to androidx and I don't want to do it right now. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

As I see when I add the above dependency in my project there are added androidx libraries. So based on this post [Error while merging dex Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387207/error-while-merging-dex-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resu) 
it seems that the only solution is to fully migrate to AndroidX.